# How do I make LLDB running from terminal respond to Swift commands?

Tags: swift, terminal, lldb

I'm trying to use LLDB from the terminal to modify code running in the simulator. I'm able to do so with Objective-C but the Swift equivalent does nothing. I've not used lldb directly in the terminal before (only through Xcode) so I may be missing something very basic. Here's what I'm doing:

### Objective-C (works)

1. The app is running in the simulator
2. I launch LLDB in the terminal and attach to the app using: `process attached -name MyApp`
3. I pause execution with `process interrupt`
4. I use `po` to modify the code (specifically `[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] connectedScenes] anyObject] keyWindow] setRootViewController: [UIViewController new]]`) which results in `<UIViewController: 0x12e13fe60>` being produced in lldb output
5. I resume the app with `process continue`

The app is in the expected state (i.e. a blank screen)

### Swift (doesn't work)

1. The app is running in the simulator
2. I launch LLDB in the terminal and attach to the app using: `process attached -name MyApp`
3. I pause execution with `process interrupt`
4. I switch language to Swift with `settings set target.language swift`
5. I use `po` to modify the code (specifically `(UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene)?.keyWindow?.rootViewController = UIViewController()`) which results in no output being produced
6. I resume the app with `process continue`

The app is in the same state as it was before the app was interrupted (and that makes me sad). The fact that evaluating Swift commands produces no output, not even an error, seems suspicious to me. This is true for all statements (e.g. In objc `po @"Hiya"`outputs `Hiya` while in swift `po "Hiya"` doesn't output anything).

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The way `po` works is that (1) lldb evaluates the expression you gave it using whatever language you have specified (this part is exactly the same as what the `p` command does).  Then (2) the `o` part instructs lldb to take the result of the expression, and call the language-specific "Object Description" API to produce a string summary of that result.

In your ObjC example, the "expression" is a method call and presumably setRootViewController: returns the new controller object, so the result is that object, and the default ObjC description produces the class & address as its summary.

In the second case you wrote an assignment.  The result of an assignment in swift is an empty tuple, so there's nothing for the Swift object description API to print.  That doesn't mean the expression didn't work, just that it didn't have a printable result.

However, for an expression that does produce a result `po` should show you the object printer's version of that result in swift as well as ObjC.  I tried your "Hiya" example on a couple different Xcode releases and I couldn't get that not to work so there must be something specific to your setup that's causing problems.

If you want to follow up on this it's probably better to file a bug with https://feedbackassistant.apple.com or with the swift OSS bug reporter (https://bugs.swift.org) as somebody's going to have to reproduce your case to figure out why this isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've cracked it! The fix was to set the version of the command line tools. I did this via Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools (could probably use `xcode-select` too).

I guess the problem was a mismatch between lldb version and related tools ‍♂️.